# convert dataset to xml (encoding="UTF-8"),

Tags: c#

I have an dataset which i need to convert to  xml with encoding="UTF-8  " specifiedin the xml  file

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dbconn);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter cmd1 = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from employee", con);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                cmd1.Fill(ds);

                string strFileName = @"E:\Dif.xml";        
                MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(); 
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(memStream, Encoding.UTF8);             
                ds.WriteXml(writer, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

i see no  xml  file  been written,
 i wante dteh xml  file  to be  written in this  format  in the heading

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

so what is teh setting that i should be  doing while converting dataset to  xml.

please help me out, i ma using vs2003,.net 1.1 framework

thanks
prince

Comment: Try using FileStream instead of MemoryStream: Your code should look like this: FileStream fs  =new FileStream(strFileName,  FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None); StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8); ds.WriteXML(writer, XMLWriteMode.WriteSchema);

Comment: +1 @Verrigo - whatever's being written isn't being written to the file at the moment - it's being written into memory. Why not post as a potential answer?

Answer (score 4):

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(strFileName, settings))
{
    ds.WriteXml(xmlWriter);
    xmlWriter.Close();
}
```

Use this can write xml with encoding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Comment: Best answer so far, I created an extension method for this.

Answer (score 2):

As per Alex's suggestion, here is my comment as an answer:
Try using FileStream instead of MemoryStream: Your code should look like this:

```
FileStream fs =new FileStream(strFileName, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None); 
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8); 
ds.WriteXML(writer, XMLWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

But also, please take a look at his anwer too, maybe the answer is a combination of both our answers.

Answer (score 1):

I used flying19880517s answer and converted it to an extension method. To get the same result as the original `WriteXml` method I added `Indent = true` (otherwise your get the xml without newlines / spaces.

```
    public static void WriteXml(this DataSet ds, string fileName, Encoding encoding)
    {
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(fileName,
            new XmlWriterSettings { Encoding = encoding, Indent = true, }))
            ds.WriteXml(writer);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema`?

Taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.xmlwritemode.aspx for `XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema`:

> Writes the current contents of the
>   DataSet as XML data with the
>   relational structure as inline XSD
>   schema. If the DataSet has only a
>   schema with no data, only the inline
>   schema is written. **If the DataSet does
>   not have a current schema, nothing is
>   written.**

Answer (score 0):

You are writing to a memory stream. Use a FileStream if you want output to disk.

Regards, Morten

Comment: thanks for the solution, now file is been written in disk, but still <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>    is not been written in xml file